# Проблема с уставновкой PYGAME

Tags: python, pygame, mac, install

Друзья! Терминал на Mac не дает установить PYGAME:
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.6)

Но в PyCharm этот пакет так и не установлен! 
И если через PyCharm, то выдает вот такую ошибку (полный текст): https://pastebin.com/ZLEe2Wre

Скрин прилагаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Помогло вот это (поочередно):

```
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi;
pip3 install pygame;
pip install pygame
```